# how to animate highcharts marker symbol on chart load

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts scatter plot with jpg's for marker symbols. When the chart loads, I would like to gently scale up and then scale down the image sizes for a few seconds so that the consumer knows that you can interact with the chart. The marker symbols are added as svg image tags by highcharts and so working with css transform/transitions are not working. I also tried adding in an animateTransform svg attribute to the image tag, but that is disrupting the way the marker symbol is placed on the chart. At the moment, I am at a loss as to what would be the best way to add a small scaling animation for a few seconds. I am currently looking into exporting my jpg's as svg paths so that they are easier to manipulate, but I don't know if that will work yet.

As an example, I would want the sun markers in this JS fiddle to scale up and then down a few times when the chart first loads. http://tinyurl.com/qj7eszh

Comment: what are you asking about? the question is too broad

Comment: @Farside I updated the description! Hope that is more clear!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update series to change `height` and `width` of series' `marker` in callback based on series of `setTimeout`s.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9tcjo4dv/

```
}, function(chart){
    var sunSeries = chart.get('sunSeries');
    setTimeout(function(){
        sunSeries.update({marker:{height: 15, width: 15}});
  }, 500);

    setTimeout(function(){
        sunSeries.update({marker:{height: 30, width: 30}});
  }, 1000);
});
```